# Gradle: Override transitive dependency by version classifier

Tags: java, maven, gradle, guava, dependency-management

One of the dependencies declared in my project has a transitive dependency on `'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'`. But my application deployed on WAS/Weblogic doesn't work due to a CDI issue which has been fixed in `'com.google.guava:guava:15.0:cdi1.0'`. (same version, but with classifier) I need to tell gradle to use this jar during build and packaging. I am trying to figure out how we can override this transitive dependency with a jar specific version classifier.

Tried the following approaches:

1. Added the dependency explicitly: `compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0:cdi1.0'`. But both jars got included in the resultant WAR.
2. Added the dependency explicitly and defined a resolution strategy:

   ```
   configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
           force 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0:cdi1.0'
       }
   }
   ```

Even this didn't work.

3. Defined a resolution strategy to check and change the version.

   ```
   configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group + ":" + details.requested.name == 'com.google.guava:guava') {
               details.useVersion "15.0:cdi1.0"
               //details.useTarget "com.google.guava:guava:15.0:cdi1.0"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Even this didn't work.

Need your suggestions on how this issue can be tackled.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Currently classifiers are not yet taken into account when it comes to *resolutionStrategies*. A workaround for you might excluding the transitive Guava library when declaring your dependencies and adding the Guava `cdi1.0` version explicitly:

```
dependencies {
    compile ("org.acme:someDependency:1.0"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    }       
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:15.0:cdi1.0"
}
```

Comment: Note that this is no longer the correct answer. See for upgrading (transitive) dependencies: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html and for downgrading or excluding (transitive) dependencies: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html

Comment: @Pieter I would encourage you to submit a new answer, since none of the current answers include the constraints answer.

Answer (score 41):

I came across a more elegant approach which is simply:

```
compile ("com.google.guava:guava:15.0:cdi1.0") {
  force = true
}
```

#### Explanation

Setting `force = true` for a dependency tells gradle to use the specified version in case of a version conflict

Comment: I get `'force' is deprecated`

Comment: @lionello Use `implementation("...") { version { strictly("...") } }`

Answer (score 17):

```
implementation( group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec'){
      version{
        strictly "[1.15]"
      }
   }
```

This works for me with gradle 6.6.1

The documentation link for  strictly can found here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html#rich-version-constraints

Answer (score 6):

Gradle 4.5.1 has the function [DependencySubstitutions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions.html). Here an example to replace a dependency:

```
configurations.each {
    c -> c.resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
            if (dependency.requested.group == 'org.json') {
                dependency.useTarget 'com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `force = true` is deprecated, relevant solution is to use `strictly(...)` version, e.g.:

```
dependencies {
    // no need to exclude transitive spring-data-relational from this dependency
    implementation("org.springframework.data", "spring-data-r2dbc", "1.1.0.RC1")

    implementation("org.springframework.data", "spring-data-relational").version {
        strictly("2.0.0.RC1")
    }
}
```

P.S. tested on Gradle 6.3

Comment: is there a documentation?.."strictly" not working in Gradle 6.4.1

Comment: @happy The documentation link which I found on strictly https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html#rich-version-constraints   implementation( group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec'){
        version{
            strictly "[1.15]"
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

This will not work if the same dependency is pointed by some other jar. Sureshot way to exclude the dependency

```
configurations {
 all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava-jdk5'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fix it by exclude `org.bouncycastle` from the module which causes this duplicate error.

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
implementation(project(Modules.yourModuleName)) {
    exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->

        // https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.guava' && details.requested.name == 'guava') {
            details.useVersion '15.0:cdi1.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where to put? Inside android tag or outside/

Answer (score 0):

try this its working perfectly  in my case in App level in  build.gradle file

```
android {
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'conceal'

    all*.exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15on'
    }
}
```