# Gradle: How to include libraries in multiple versions to satisfy dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I need to use two libraries in my Java Gradle project. Both of these libraries have a dependency to Google Guava (`com.google.common`).

The problem is that one library requires Guava 19.0, and the other requires Guava 23.0. The public API of Guava had some **breaking changes** between 19.0 and 23.0, so I cannot simply force the dependency to be solely Guava 23.0 (e.g. as proposed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30729087/3094906)).

Is there any way to resolve this issue within Gradle itself?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : no

Gradle does not support more than one version of the same library when compiling the code. The default behaviour is to take the newest one when a conflict is spotted but it can be changed overriding the [Resolution Strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)

But in your case, none of these options will help you.

Comment: Which means, I'm out of luck? What other options are there? I never looked into the topic so far, but isn't there something like "shadow jars" or "shaded jars" that should help in such cases?