# Gradle could not find guava-*version*-cdi1.0.jar

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Might be something obvious, but this issue got me stuck for a while.

Some of the libraries require `com.google.guava:guava:21.0` as the dependency, however gradle **fails to fetch it from the maven repository**. it's a legacy project, so versions are not the latest.

**Error log:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find guava-21.0-cdi1.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:21.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0-cdi1.0.jar
```

`guava-21.0.jar`  (without `-cdi1.0` suffix) exists on that path. Why does gradle ads the `-cdi1.0` suffix to the filename and is it possible to disable this feature? or i simply misunderstanding something and there is something else in play?

i tried to specify `guava` dep separately `compile(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '21.0')`, however it doesn't affect anything.

**build.gradle:** (generated by `gradle init` from maven pom.xml)

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.4.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.4.1.RELEASE'
    ... etc other deps
}

group = 'com.springapp'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'someproj'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

from `gradle --debug build`:

```
2021-01-31T10:59:27.736-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre using repositories [MavenRepo, maven]
2021-01-31T10:59:27.736-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Using cached module metadata for module 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre' in 'MavenRepo'
2021-01-31T10:59:27.737-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Using com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre from Maven repository 'MavenRepo'
2021-01-31T10:59:27.737-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Candidate com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration compile doesn't have attribute org.gradle.dependency.bundling
2021-01-31T10:59:27.737-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Candidate com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration compile doesn't have attribute org.gradle.jvm.version
2021-01-31T10:59:27.737-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Candidate com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration runtime doesn't have attribute org.gradle.dependency.bundling
2021-01-31T10:59:27.737-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Candidate com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration runtime doesn't have attribute org.gradle.jvm.version
2021-01-31T10:59:27.738-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Candidate com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration platform-compile attribute org.gradle.category value {org.gradle.category=platform, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api} doesn't requested value library
2021-01-31T10:59:27.738-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Candidate com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration platform-runtime attribute org.gradle.category value {org.gradle.category=platform, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime} doesn't requested value library
2021-01-31T10:59:27.738-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Candidate com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration enforced-platform-compile attribute org.gradle.category value {org.gradle.category=enforced-platform, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api} doesn't requested value library
2021-01-31T10:59:27.738-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Candidate com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration enforced-platform-runtime attribute org.gradle.category value {org.gradle.category=enforced-platform, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime} doesn't requested value library
2021-01-31T10:59:27.738-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.ComponentAttributeMatcher] Selected matches [com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration compile] from candidates [com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration compile, com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration runtime, com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration platform-compile, com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration platform-runtime, com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration enforced-platform-compile, com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre configuration enforced-platform-runtime] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}
```

and then later:

```
2021-01-31T10:59:27.938-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Found artifact 'guava-30.1-jre.jar (com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre)' in resolver cache: /Users/hopa/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/30.1-jre/d0c3ce2311c9e36e73228da25a6e99b2ab826f/guava-30.1-jre.jar
2021-01-31T10:59:27.940-0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of artifact 'guava-30.1-jre-cdi1.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre)' in resolver cache
```

this is the only time when cdi classifier is mentioned in debug log `Detected non-existence of artifact 'guava-30.1-jre-cdi1.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre)' in resolver cache`, except for the build fail message

Comment: Can you run with `—scan` and paste the result here?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example please ?

Comment: which version of gradle are you using ?

Comment: tried `6.3`, `6.6`

Comment: Provide full dependencies list. Edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cdi-1.0` suffix is a classifier, usually seen in a pom like: `<classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>`.  As far as I can see, it's really only in Guava 15, so I would check everywhere to try to find the offender.  Some things to try:

- Check transitive dependencies.  Use `gradle dependencies` to look for what is trying to pull in `com.google.guava:guava:21.0` and the incorrect classifier.  Maybe one of those is doing so incorrectly and you can try changing versions or forcing something different.  Hopefully forcing doesn't cause [too much trouble with the classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728533/gradle-override-transitive-dependency-by-version-classifier).  Time permitting, you could try to find the dependency poms that might be mismatched.
- Restart / Invalidate Caches in your IDE, as well as clearing Gradle cache.

Comment: yep, i did all of those - checked dep tree, it is resolved to `com.google.guava:guava:21.0-jre` , without `cdi` classifier, cleared gradle and IDE caches, tried to update all deps, still failing on `guava` with `cdi`

Comment: also tried to use `force` and `strictly`, but it doesn't seem to impact the usage of `cdi` classifier